# How to generate a DH shared key if the peer public key is not encoded as the host private key?

Tags: python, cryptography, elliptic-curve, diffie-hellman

I'm trying to perform a DH key exchange between a host (python) and a device (using C).
I'm currently using [cryptography.io's elliptic curve exchange algorithm](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/ec/#elliptic-curve-key-exchange-algorithm) on the host.

This is the situation:
I have received the peer's public key as a list of 64 integers, raw as it is, no padding no wrapping no encyption.

However, when I have to generate the shared key, the example shows this:

```
shared_key = private_key.exchange(ec.ECDH(), peer_public_key)
```

But throws an error, ofc:

```
AttributeError 'list' object has no attribute 'curve'
```

It should be because my private key is a _EllipticCurvePrivateKey object, while the peer public key is just a list.

How do I turn my peer public key to a suitable public key to generate the shared secret?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cryptography supports the import of *raw* EC keys with the methods [`ec.EllipticCurvePublicKey.from_encoded_point()`](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/ec/#cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric.ec.EllipticCurvePublicKey.from_encoded_point) (since version 2.5) for the public key and [`ec.derive_private_key()`](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/ec/#cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric.ec.derive_private_key) (since version 1.6) for the private key.

Example (for elliptic curve secp256k1):

```python
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import ec

curve = ec.SECP256K1()

# Key A: Generate a new key pair
private_keyA = ec.generate_private_key(curve)
public_keyA = private_keyA.public_key()

#Key B: Derive key pair from raw data
private_valueB = 0x36A4B92DCD0077CDA3173D218733931497582B733285B8961CAD616E927691B9
public_valueB = bytes.fromhex('04D4465B9B77F9811BF89B20064A5214C00210D6183910BDC220BA65F8B9D327933C1D7FD3B7DB0A69420A614C9D9303D09BA96C83203927B149A6E28D01E0C253')
private_keyB = ec.derive_private_key(private_valueB, curve, default_backend())
public_keyB = ec.EllipticCurvePublicKey.from_encoded_point(curve, public_valueB)

# Shared Keys
shared_keyA = private_keyA.exchange(ec.ECDH(), public_keyB)
print(shared_keyA.hex())

shared_keyB = private_keyB.exchange(ec.ECDH(), public_keyA)
print(shared_keyB.hex())
```

In the posted code, key pair A is newly generated, while key pair B is generated from raw data. When the code is executed, these keys generate the same secret on both sides as expected.

Please note regarding the public key, that the point representing the public key can be passed to `from_encoded_point()` in *compressed* (only x coordinate) or *uncompressed* format (both, x and y coordinates), see e.g. [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/56442), with a starting byte indicating whether the key is in compressed or uncompressed format.
For example, if the point is to be passed in uncompressed format, the starting byte is 0x04, followed by the bytes of the x coordinate and then the bytes of the y coordinate (giving a total length of 65 bytes for the above example).
If the data is not available in the required format, it must be converted accordingly (manually or programmatically) before it is passed to `from_encoded_point()`.

Comment: Thank you. I've tried the procedure for the public key (this one `public_keyB = ec.EllipticCurvePublicKey.from_encoded_point(curve, public_valueB)`), but it raises an error `ValueError Unsupported elliptic curve point type`. I think it could be because the key is not generated with python with the same crypto library but with another one?

Comment: As long as the point is valid, it does not matter which library was used to create it. The error message _ValueError: Unsupported elliptic curve point type_ occurs e.g. if the starting byte is missing (0x04 for an uncompressed key). Did you add the starting byte as described (see also my example)? If the problem persists, please specify the curve used and (if possible) post an example for the public key used.

Comment: I didn't understand that I to add it by hand. Now it's working! Thank you a lot!

Comment: @re.sole - I have revised the last section and hope that it is now clearer to understand. Glad that it works.